# Show message in empty cells in GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm importing `GridView` from excel 
I need to show a message near every empty cell to give the user information about what it should be writing..

```
void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string[] msg = new string[60];
    string[] error = new string[400];
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView3.RowCount ; i++)
    {
        System.Data.DataRow Rows = gridView3.GetDataRow(i);
        string cellvalue = Rows[0].ToString();
        if (cellvalue == "")
        {
            msg[0] = "Missing 'First Name'";
            error[i] = msg[0] + " - ";  
        }   
        cellvalue = Rows[1].ToString();
        if (cellvalue == "")
        {
            msg[1] = "Missing 'Last Name'";
            error[i] += msg[1] + " - ";
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

How can I put the variable `msg[]` to the specific cell with a little image or `"!"` figure or maybe I can color the cell

Comment: Maybe you can use a `ToolTip`

Comment: ASPxGridView? XtraGrid? DXGrid? have you tried posting this question in [Devex Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) ?

Comment: No I didn't.. I'm using XtraGrid.. not ASP.net

Comment: The `System.Data.DataRow` already contains a property which indicates that there's an error with the row (`System.Data.DataRow.RowError`) which is usually blank. If you would like to indicate that there's an error with the row, you can change this to the error's text. When this property is not blank, an exclamation mark should appear next to the row. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

To change the color of cell

```
Rows[1].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

Comment: I'm searching for any solution to be able to get to my point.. I need to be able to let the user know which cell need to be modified and show a message concerning this empty cell

@Arun C.B you're right about what you wrote.. Thank You 
But i still need the message

Answer (score 2):

You can color the XtraGrid cells using [Conditional Formatting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2406) feature:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = new List<Person> { 
    new Person(){ Name = "John", Age = 25 },
    new Person(){ Name = "Mary", Age = 17 },
    new Person(){ Age = 17  },
    new Person(){ Name = "Ann" },
    new Person(){ Name = "Pit", Age = 5 },
};
StyleFormatCondition nameCondition = new StyleFormatCondition();
nameCondition.Column = gridView1.Columns["Name"];
nameCondition.Condition = FormatConditionEnum.Expression;
nameCondition.Expression = "IsNullOrEmpty([Name])";
nameCondition.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
nameCondition.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = true;

StyleFormatCondition ageCondition = new StyleFormatCondition();
ageCondition.Column = gridView1.Columns["Age"];
ageCondition.Condition = FormatConditionEnum.Expression;
ageCondition.Expression = "[Age]<10";
ageCondition.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
ageCondition.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = true;

gridView1.FormatConditions.AddRange(new StyleFormatCondition[] { 
    nameCondition, ageCondition
});
```

Result:
[image: XtraGrid Conditional Formatting]

Related Links:
[Customizing Appearances of Individual Rows and Cells](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3495)
[Style Format Conditions](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument759)
[Custom Painting (Samples)](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument763)

Comment: I'm gonna try this method now and let you know if everything goes right.. Thank You

Comment: +1 for cell formatting, @Nejthe above code is for Back color changing for empty cells.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a `ToolTip` to show your alert:

```
toolTip1.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Warning;
toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Warning!";
toolTip1.Show("Missing 'First Name'", x, y);
```

You only need to guess the location of the cell based on the sizes of the rows and columns of the `DataGridView`.

[image: Example1]  [image: Example2]

`ToolTip` is in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

Comment: `ToolTip` is in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea.. you know I have 50 columns I can't know the location of the cell.. But I really appreciate your help

Comment: You can calculate the location of the cell based on the values you can get from your `DataGridView`. You can make a function to tell you the locations.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: [How to: Provide Custom Display Text for Data Cells](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3077)

> To provide custom display text for data cells via the
>   [ColumnView.CustomColumnDisplayText](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic.aspx) event. To more information
>   regarding customdrawing and cell styling go through [Custom Painting
>   Samples](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument763), [Customizing Appearances of Individual Rows and Cells](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument758.aspx)
>   documentation section.

check the example empty strings are displayed within the "Discount" column's cells if they contain zero values.

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;

private void gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, 
CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e) {
   if(e.Column.FieldName == "Discount")
      if(Convert.ToDecimal(e.Value) == 0) e.DisplayText = "";
}
```

If you want to show `Image and text` both then you need to handle the [GridView.CustomDrawCell](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic.aspx) event of your GridView, here is a snip of code that change the color of the Name column, based on an other column valoe (age column)

```
private void gridView_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column == colName)
        {
            var age = Convert.ToInt32(gridView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, colAge));
            if (age < 18)
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xFE, 0xDF, 0x98);
            else
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xD2, 0xFD, 0x91);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why I don't have the CustomColumnDisplayText in my events ?
Do You have any idea ? 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: View have this event, not the GridControl

Comment: use `gridView1.CustomColumnDisplayText += event handler`.