# Color a null cell not all the cells

Tags: c#, devexpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show message in empty cells in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603391/show-message-in-empty-cells-in-gridview)

By That code i am getting all the cells colored
I just need the empty one.. Can someone notice where's my fault (Sorry I'm new to C#)

```
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] msg = new string[60];
        string[] error = new string[400];
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView3.RowCount ; i++)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow Rows = gridView3.GetDataRow(i);
            string cellvalue = Rows[0].ToString();
            if (cellvalue == "")
            {
                msg[0] = "Missing 'First Name'";
                error[i] = msg[0] + " - ";  
                gridView3.CustomDrawCell += new RowCellCustomDrawEventHandler(gridView3_CustomDrawCell);

            }
        }
    }
    private void gridView3_CustomDrawCell_1(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Style.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
    }
```

By the way this grid was imported from Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register grid event only once, not in the loop.
For cell coloring use [RowCellStyle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic) event.

[Customizing Appearances of Individual Rows and Cells help topic](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think you need to also loop its cells, i.e.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView3.Rows)
{
  foreach (GridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
  {
    if (cell.Text == "")
    {
     //Do stuff here color etc
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have access to the CELL object you can set the color there, i.e. (System.Drawing namespace)

```
cell.BackColor = Color.Green
```

Comment: I am getting this error in the first line

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator', or it is inaccessible

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like 
`String.IsNullOrEmpty(cellvalue)`
If True then do your thing.

As said, you might want to loop through cells first